# Android -FragmentStatePagerAdapter change amount of Fragments instantiated

Tags: android, fragmentstatepageradapter

FragmentStatePagerAdapter creates about 3 fragments each time.  I'd like it to create say 10 fragments to populate the viewpager at once.  I dont see any methods to change the default.  Im dealing with a large number of items and each fragment in the adapter makes a network call thus some overhead on each new page traversal.  I'd like to cut it down by keeping more items in the adapter at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a hold of your `ViewPager` and use `setOffscreenPageLimit(10);`

Comment: This return java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: error.